# NestedScrollView doesn't behave correctly when the body is a Navigator that wraps a ListView

Tags: flutter

I have created a NestedScrollView with an appBar and a Navigator body:

```
NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
              SliverAppBar(
                  leading: Container(),
                  pinned: false,
                  snap: false,
                  floating: true
              )
            ],
            body: Navigator(
                key: widget.navigatorKey,
                initialRoute: kDefaultPage,
                onPopPage: (route, result) => false,
                onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => _buildBody(settings)
                )
            )
        )
```

(_buildBody always returns a ListView).
Considering the options that I passed to SliverAppBar, I would expect it to be hidden when the user scrolls the NestedScrollView's body(a ListView). Instead, the SliverAppBar remains fixed.

The strange this is that if I flip the Navigator and NestedScrollView, everything works:

```
Navigator(
        key: widget.navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: kDefaultPage,
        onPopPage: (route, result) => false,
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NestedScrollView(
                headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
                  SliverAppBar(
                      leading: Container(),
                      pinned: false,
                      snap: false,
                      floating: true
                  )
                ],
                body: _buildBody(settings)
            )
        )
    )
```

This solution isn't optimal though as I need n SliverAppBar instead of only one, which messes up the animations when using the navigator. Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an solution.

You can use a CustomScrollView with a SliverAppBar and a SliverFillRemaining child that contains the Navigator. This way, the SliverAppBar will be aware of the scroll events happening inside the Navigator.

**Example (Not tested):**

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverAppBar(
      leading: Container(),
      pinned: false,
      snap: false,
      floating: true,
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      child: Navigator(
        key: widget.navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: kDefaultPage,
        onPopPage: (route, result) => false,
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => _buildBody(settings),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

**Changes made:**

1. Instead of using NestedScrollView use CustomScrollView. This widget allows you to combine multiple sliver-based widgets :) into a scrollable area.
2. I placed the SliverAppBar directly inside the CustomScrollView's slivers list. This will make the SliverAppBar a part of the main scrollable area and hopefully respond to scroll events.
3. Inside of SliverFillRemaining widget, I placed the Navigator.
   By doing this, hopefully the the Navigator becomes a part of the main scrollable area, and the SliverAppBar will be aware of the scroll events
   happening inside the Navigator.

Hope this helps.